# MYSQL/PHP count answers to reoccurring questions

Tags: php, mysql, sql, report

Im a little bit confused to how i should even do this. But i will try to explain the best i can.

Im creating a report that will look something like this:

[image]

But with a lot more questions.

So multiple people have answered this survey and all the records are in the database which i need to work with to produce this report.

I have created the query that pulls back all the releveant data from joining multiple tables seen below:

**Tables**
-survey
-surveyEntries
-surveyQuestions
-survey_meta
-hw_services

```
        SELECT
            `surveyEntries`.`ID` AS EntryID,
            `surveyEntries`.`created` AS EntryDate,
            `hw_services`.`name` AS Provider,
            `surveyQuestions`.`ID` AS QuestionID,
            `surveyQuestions`.`label` AS Question,
            `survey_meta`.`answer` AS Answer,
          `surveyQuestions`.`parentID` AS ParentQuestion
        FROM `survey`
        JOIN `surveyQuestions`
            ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`
        JOIN `surveyEntries`
            ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
        JOIN `survey_meta`
             ON (`surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID` AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`)
        JOIN `hw_services`
            ON `surveyEntries`.`hw_serviceID` = `hw_services`.`ID`
        WHERE `hw_services`.`healthwatchID` = '1'
        AND `survey`.`ID` = '1'
        AND `surveyQuestions`.`type` IN ('radio', 'dropdown')
        AND `hw_services`.`ID` = '1697'
```

Okay no just to demonstrate this is a picture of the data i am pulling back. There are a total of 30 questions in the survey but for here im just showing 4 rows for each entry.

[image]

[image]

So they are the same questions etc but different entries.

Now how can i go about this?

and get the number that said yes and the number that said no in each question so that i can produce this in php?

IF you need any further information please let me know.

Comment: Add a `COUNT(*) AS Total` to your `SELECT` and then add a `GROUP BY \`surveyQuestions\`.\`ID\`, \`survey_meta\`.\`answer\``

Comment: @Sean could you please put this in an answer for me as im not exactly sure how to implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have all the data we can use `group by` in order to see counts of all the unique answers for each question. To do this we could use something like the following:

```
SELECT QuestionId, Question, Answer, count(*) 
FROM (PUT YOUR SELECT HERE) 
GROUP BY QuestionId, Answer
```

That will then give you each question (and its id), with unique answer for that question and a count of that unique answer.

Or to do it all in the one select you provided:

```
SELECT
            `surveyEntries`.`ID` AS EntryID,
            `surveyEntries`.`created` AS EntryDate,
            `hw_services`.`name` AS Provider,
            `surveyQuestions`.`ID` AS QuestionID,
            `surveyQuestions`.`label` AS Question,
            `survey_meta`.`answer` AS Answer,
             count(*) as Total,
            `surveyQuestions`.`parentID` AS ParentQuestion
        FROM `survey`
        JOIN `surveyQuestions`
            ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`
        JOIN `surveyEntries`
            ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
        JOIN `survey_meta`
             ON (`surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID` AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`)
        JOIN `hw_services`
            ON `surveyEntries`.`hw_serviceID` = `hw_services`.`ID`
        WHERE `hw_services`.`healthwatchID` = '1'
        AND `survey`.`ID` = '1'
        AND `surveyQuestions`.`type` IN ('radio', 'dropdown')
        AND `hw_services`.`ID` = '1697'
        GROUP BY `surveyQuestions`.`ID`, `survey_meta`.`answer`
```

where i have added `count(*)` into the initial select and `GROUP BY surveyQuestions.ID, survey_meta.answer` at the end

Comment: thanks for this, i think this is exactly what i need on the mysql side of things. Just need to do this with php now :), by the way you missed a comma after the Total.

Comment: Infact , can this be edited to show a row with the answer even if it has 0? for example for ethnicity i have 5 possible answers in this case only 4 answers where chosen so in the table it only shows 4 , but i need it to show 5 and put a 0 next to the option

Answer (score 0):

For GENDER report you can use this sql

```
SELECT
        `survey_meta`.`answer` AS Gender,
        COUNT(*) AS 'Total Answer'
    FROM `survey`
    JOIN `surveyQuestions`
        ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`
    JOIN `surveyEntries`
        ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
    JOIN `survey_meta`
         ON (`surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID` AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`)
    JOIN `hw_services`
        ON `surveyEntries`.`hw_serviceID` = `hw_services`.`ID`
    WHERE `hw_services`.`healthwatchID` = '1'
    AND `survey`.`ID` = '1'
    AND `surveyQuestions`.`type` IN ('radio', 'dropdown')
    AND `hw_services`.`ID` = '1697'
    AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = 9
GROUP BY `survey_meta`.`answer`
```

For AGE GROUP report, similar with above, just change `surveyQuestions`.`ID`. So the code would be like this

```
SELECT
        `survey_meta`.`answer` AS Gender,
        COUNT(*) AS 'Total Answer'
    FROM `survey`
    JOIN `surveyQuestions`
        ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyQuestions`.`surveyID`
    JOIN `surveyEntries`
        ON `survey`.`ID` = `surveyEntries`.`surveyID`
    JOIN `survey_meta`
         ON (`surveyEntries`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`entryID` AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = `survey_meta`.`questionID`)
    JOIN `hw_services`
        ON `surveyEntries`.`hw_serviceID` = `hw_services`.`ID`
    WHERE `hw_services`.`healthwatchID` = '1'
    AND `survey`.`ID` = '1'
    AND `surveyQuestions`.`type` IN ('radio', 'dropdown')
    AND `hw_services`.`ID` = '1697'
    AND `surveyQuestions`.`ID` = 10
GROUP BY `survey_meta`.`answer`
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. However there is a lot more questions than just the gender and age group one, i only put those two down as they are they different choices available. So every question is either answer 1 or answer 2 and the age range is the only type where there is a multiple choice of 5 answers.

Comment: how can i approach this?